# MongoDB Length of String or need help in mongoDB mapReduce query

Tags: mongodb

I need some guidence in a query for mongodb.  I have a collection of items which contain an array that contains multiple fields, but I only care about one field, which is the barcode field.  I need to distiguish the length of the barcode string.

```
Items.find({this.array['barcode'].length > 6})
```

It would be great if the above query was possible, but I believe that it's not.  I only need a list of barcodes.  How do I go about solving this problem?  Does mongodb have something to compare length of a string?  Or do I have to use a mapReduce query?  If I do could I have some guidence on that?  I'm not sure how I would go about writing it.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a regular expression.
`/^\w{6}/` this says match a word that has 6 word characters at the start of the string.

Example:

Setup:

```
user test;
var createProduct = function(name, barcode){
  return {
    name : name,
    detail: {
      barcode : barcode
    }
  };
};
db.products.drop();
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  db.products.insert( createProduct( "product" + i, "1234567890".substring(0,i+1) ));
}
```

Document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("540d3ba1242ff352caa6154b"),
    "name" : "product0",
    "detail" : {
        "barcode" : "1"
    }
}
```

Query:

```
db.products.find({ "detail.barcode" : /^\w{6}/ })
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540d3ba1242ff352caa61550"), "name" : "product5", "detail" : { "barcode" : "123456" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540d3ba1242ff352caa61551"), "name" : "product6", "detail" : { "barcode" : "1234567" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540d3ba1242ff352caa61552"), "name" : "product7", "detail" : { "barcode" : "12345678" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540d3ba1242ff352caa61553"), "name" : "product8", "detail" : { "barcode" : "123456789" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540d3ba1242ff352caa61554"), "name" : "product9", "detail" : { "barcode" : "1234567890" } }
```

However, if `barcode` is a key within an object inside an array AND you only want the matched barcode values. Then you should use an aggregate function to extract the values.

Setup:

```
user test;
var createProduct = function(name){
  var o = {
    name : name,
    subProducts: []
  };
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    o.subProducts.push({
      barcode : "1234567890".substring(0,i+1)
    });
  }
  return o;
};
db.products.drop();
db.products.insert( createProduct( "newBrand") );
```

Document Structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("540d4125242ff352caa61555"),
    "name" : "newBrand",
    "subProducts" : [
        {
            "barcode" : "1"
        },
...
        {
            "barcode" : "123456789"
        },
        {
            "barcode" : "1234567890"
        }
    ]
}
```

Aggregate Query:

```
db.products.aggregate([
  { $unwind : "$subProducts" },
  { $match : { "subProducts.barcode" : /^\w{6}/ } }
]);
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540d4125242ff352caa61555"), "name" : "newBrand", "subProducts" : { "barcode" : "123456" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540d4125242ff352caa61555"), "name" : "newBrand", "subProducts" : { "barcode" : "1234567" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540d4125242ff352caa61555"), "name" : "newBrand", "subProducts" : { "barcode" : "12345678" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540d4125242ff352caa61555"), "name" : "newBrand", "subProducts" : { "barcode" : "123456789" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("540d4125242ff352caa61555"), "name" : "newBrand", "subProducts" : { "barcode" : "1234567890" } }
```

More info:

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/
- [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: Thanks Larry, I had troubles with your regex so I just changed mine to  { $match : { "barcode" : /^.{0,6}$/ } }

Comment: So I got the result of 

[ 0:{ _id:<barcode> }, 1:{ _id:<barcode> } ... ].  

Is there anyway to change this to be just an array of barcodes?  ie) [<barcode>, <barcode>...]  
Here is my updated query.

db.Items.aggregate([
  { $unwind : "$item" },
  { $match : { "item.barcode" : /^.{0,6}$/ },
  { $project: { "item.barcode" : 1, "_id":0 } },
  { $group : { "_id" : "$item.barcode"} },
  { $limit : 100 }
])

Comment: @raging_sub Please update your question with a sample document.